# Change selected-item foreground color Eclipse IDE (Windwows)

Tags: eclipse, themes

I have my Eclipse (Luna) set up to use the Eclipse *Dark* theme, and the *Classic Theme* for Color and Fonts.

I also have the *Obsidian* Color Theme.

The majority of the UI is perfect, but in certain areas (specifically the Breakpoints window in the Debug view) selected/highlighted items have a black-font (foreground color).

[image: Highlighted item in Debug window has black foreground]

As you can see in the above image, the text (foreground) color of the selected item in the Breakpoints window is black, which makes it very hard to read.

I've looked through the *Preferences -> Appearnce -> Colors and Fonts* section, but have not been able to pinpoint which setting corresponds to this case.

If anyone has any insight I would greatly appreciate it.

Thanks!

Comment: PS If you upload screenshots in png instead of jpg you don't have compression artefacts like your screenshot does. Some of the improvements in Mars are down to icons themselves better supporting dark themes, but I can't tell from your screenshot if my answer's screenshot shows improvements or compression artefacts.

Comment: Thanks very much for your response, it definitely depicts that the issue I mentioned is resolved in Mars. I will also keep in mind your advice regarding jpg/png images. I have accepted your answer, and hope that migrating from Luna to Mars is not too troublesome a process. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is Eclipse Luna.  Eclipse Luna was the first version of Eclipse to come with a proper built-in dark theme, and over the last two years a number of the minor issues (like you have found) have been fixed.

This is fixed in Eclipse Mars, and I expect to be even better for upcoming Eclipse Neon.

Here is an equivalent screenshot on Mars with the built-in dark theme.

[image]

As you can see your particular issue is fixed, and a number of other issues are fixed too, like the tab background colour. There are certainly other areas that still need tuning (e.g. the Details of breakpoints still has dark labels), and the best way to get that done is:

1. [Contribute a fix](https://eclipse.org/contribute/)
2. [File a bug](https://bugs.eclipse.org/bugs/enter_bug.cgi?product=Platform&component=UI)